# Request: Microsoft SQL Server JDBC Driver 1.1

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jar

I have an old Java project which I need to rebuild from a Maven Ant task and which has a lot of dependencies. Unfortunately the support repository server does not exist any more and some of the files were not in the project's code repository either so I have to look them up for myself.

Anyway, I have trouble finding a certain library, `microsoft:sqlserver-jdbc:jar:1.1` as the log says. In other words, it should be a file called `sqlserver-jdbc-1.1.jar` or something similar.

Newer versions of it can be found easily but I am not sure if they will fit. Maybe someone can help me out here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you may not adhere to the bugs of this old MS driver I'd recommend you to use [JTDS driver](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/).

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to be possible atm. The only dependency I can change from the build files is log4j, others are from project's jar files but I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Playing around with different Maven repositories I've managed to get it. Link if somebody other than me should ever need this: [sqlserver-jdbc-1.1.jar](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/12256259/alkor/sqlserver-jdbc-1.1.jar). Anyways, thanks for the answer, I'll consider your recommendation and mark it as accepted. :)

Answer (score 2):

The Microsoft JDBC 1.1 driver is no longer supported that is why it is no longer available for download.  The JDBC 1.2 driver is available to SAP customers who are using JRE 1.4 from service.sap.com.  The JDBC 2.0, 3.0 and 4.0 drivers are available for download from Microsoft.com and support JRE 5 & 6.